# How to know positive and negative in breadboard

Tags: power, android, prototype, voltage, breadboard

I have this breadboard, and there is no indication on it about what is positive/negative on it.

[image]

In comparison, this other breadboard (pic from the internet) DOES have indications:

[image]

Can anyone give me a hint ?

Comment: Hint: there is no negative or positive.

Comment: @gre_gor like this https://www.pjrc.com/store/breadboard.jpg I want to wire two pins to ground on breadboard

Comment: @Williams You could do that as usually as you would with a printed or marked board.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You could label them yourself with a red and blue permanent marker.

Comment: Also from my experience, your breadboard has side rails wider apart than the other breadboard and a power supply intended for a breadboard won't fit.

Comment: Here;s the rub:  Don't forget what you have chosen.  Wiring power backwards is hard on some components.  I make a point of always using the same color of wires for power to everything, and as long as the same colors are on the same rails I don't need to look at breadboard markings.  Have fun!

Comment: btw, I have used those power supplies for breadboards.  Be wary.  Their QC is not good.  I don't use them any more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You decide which rails are positive and which are negative when you connect them to the + an - from your power supply or battery.

A breadboard isn't polarised *per se*. It's just a bunch of cross-connections inside a perforated plastic case. No active or passive components inside.

Some manufacturers may choose to paint indications regarding where to connect the positive and negative rails, but those are just a guideline. Ultimately it's your choice, you're free to connect + and - wherever you want in the breadboard rails.

Comment: so If I wire GND of battery to first row, do I need to plug other wires which need to be GND besides to that wire in a same row ?

Comment: Yes indeed. Moreover, if you find it convenient to use a row in the opposite side of the breadboard as GND too, just connect it via wire to the first GND row and boom, you've got another GND row. As simple and easy as that.

Answer (score 3):

As gre_gor said. A simple breadboard contains of rows and columns of connections but sometimes for convenience manufacturer marks or prints Positive and Negative symbol along the row as they are usually used to power a circuit

Answer (score 0):

Connections in the two strips along the edge running top to bottom in your image are connected (in the way you have the image placed) top to bottom.  So, all pins are connected to each other in each of those rows.  Within the inner secions, the connections are (in your image) across from one side to the other.

You decide how you want the power supply cable to be connected to your breadboard,  just becasue there's no indicators means that they simply haven't drawn any coloured lines on the breadboard.  You can draw red and black lines on however you wish.